# Why is storing logs in root incorrect?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, logging, system-administration

I was instructed to never store my logs in  root as in "/". I was just wondering if someone could give me the logic behind this ? It may sound dumb but I feel the understanding is necessary for me to improve.

`I have moved the logs, and they are not in the root, I was just looking to get a greater understanding of why?`

Comment: It's incredibly weird to store logs in `/` on a normal system, but I can imagine someone doing it in a Docker image or other per-application container system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

root as in `/` is the very root of the file system, and there is a predefined structure and order what goes where.

root as in `/root` is the `root` user's home folder, and as such it holds different purpose.

While you CAN store logs in mostly ANY folder, you are advised not to, as the commonly accepted standard is for the logs to be in /var/log/` folder again structured further in categories/folders

Comment: I see so other than following current standards/patterns it works the same? . I was just making sure it was not a security risk, or something deeper under the hood. So it's more about convention than functionality ?

Comment: I would not say it works the same. Different folders can be on different disk partitions with different sizes, so you might be restricted writing a big log in a small /root partition, where as /var is commonly accepted to hold big chunks of data thus it is planned big. You could also be restricted by permissions.. and depending where you are and what user are you using, there will be permissions required to write/read/execute files/folders.

Comment: Just to note, there is a growing trend to mount `/` read-only, which means storing logs in `/` may be impossible.

Comment: indeed this is correct. our security dev ops team set some of the boxes at mount read only.